# Cannot find the code for this operation

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to make it so if `Label3.Text` shows *Incorrect*, then the form's background colour changes to red and if it shows *Correct*, then it turns green

```
Public Class Form1
    'Here I am declaring the varibles globally across the code
    Dim number1, number2 As Integer
    Dim rn As New Random
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        'When the form loads the lebel 1 and label 2 will already load with random numbers between 0 - 100
        number1 = rn.Next(0, 100)
        number2 = rn.Next(0, 100)
        Label1.Text = number1
        Label2.Text = number2
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        'When you click the button it will then give you a new set of random numbers
        number1 = rn.Next(0, 100)
        number2 = rn.Next(0, 100)
        Label1.Text = number1
        Label2.Text = number2
    End Sub

    Private Sub RadioButton1_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RadioButton1.CheckedChanged
        'The operators is making sure that the 2 numbers are equal to each other and then if its equal
        'it will say it is correct or if it is false it will show incorrect
        If number1 = number2 Then
            Label3.Text = "Correct"
        Else
            Label3.Text = "Incorrect"
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub RadioButton2_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RadioButton2.CheckedChanged
        'The operators is making sure that the 2 numbers are equal to each other and then if its equal
        'it will say it is correct or if it is false it will show incorrect
        If number1 <> number2 Then
            Label3.Text = "Correct"
        Else
            Label3.Text = "Incorrect"
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub RadioButton3_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RadioButton3.CheckedChanged
        'The operators is making sure that the left number is smaller than
        'the value on the right and if thats true
        'it will say it is correct or if it is false it will show incorrect
        If number1 < number2 Then
            Label3.Text = "Correct"
        Else
            Label3.Text = "Incorrect"
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub RadioButton4_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RadioButton4.CheckedChanged
        'The operators is making sure that the left number is smaller than
        'the value on the right or if it equal and if thats true
        'it will say it is correct or if it is false it will show incorrect
        If number1 <= number2 Then
            Label3.Text = "Correct"
        Else
            Label3.Text = "Incorrect"
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub RadioButton5_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RadioButton5.CheckedChanged
        'The operators is making sure that the left number is bigger than
        'the value on the right and if thats true
        'it will say it is correct or if it is false it will show incorrect
        If number1 > number2 Then
            Label3.Text = "Correct"
        Else
            Label3.Text = "Incorrect"
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub RadioButton6_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RadioButton6.CheckedChanged
        'The operators is making sure that the left number is bigger than
        'the value on the right or if it equal and if thats true
        'it will say it is correct or if it is false it will show incorrect
        If number1 >= number2 Then
            Label3.Text = "Correct"
        Else
            Label3.Text = "Incorrect"
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Label3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Label3.Click

    End Sub

    Private Sub Label3_EnabledChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Label3.EnabledChanged
        If Label3.Text = "Incorrect" Then
            Me.BackColor = Color.AliceBlue
        Else
            Label3.Text = "Correct"
            Me.BackColor = Color.Coral
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: what's your code?

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Does the code fail somewhere in particular? Can you point out where?

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your code

```
Private Sub Label3_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Label3.TextChanged
    If Label3.Text = "Incorrect" Then
        Me.BackColor = Color.Red
    ElseIf Label3.Text = "Correct" Then
        Me.BackColor = Color.Green
    End If
End Sub
```

If you find yourself writing very similar code over and over, you should put it in a method. Think if your form having two states: correct and incorrect. In each state, the UI has a specific look. When correct, the label says correct and the form is green. When incorrect, the label says incorrect and the form is red. So you can use this method in place of the `TextChanged` handler I supplied above.

```
Private Sub updateUI(isCorrect As Boolean)
    If isCorrect Then
        Label3.Text = "Correct"
        Me.BackColor = Color.Green
    Else
        Label3.Text = "Incorrect"
        Me.BackColor = Color.Red
    End If
End Sub
```

Which greatly simplifies your radio button handlers. In lines of code and maintainability

```
Private Sub RadioButton1_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RadioButton1.CheckedChanged
    updateUI(number1 = number2)
End Sub

Private Sub RadioButton2_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RadioButton2.CheckedChanged
    updateUI(number1 <> number2)
End Sub

Private Sub RadioButton3_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RadioButton3.CheckedChanged
    updateUI(number1 < number2)
End Sub

Private Sub RadioButton4_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RadioButton4.CheckedChanged
    updateUI(number1 <= number2)
End Sub

Private Sub RadioButton5_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RadioButton5.CheckedChanged
    updateUI(number1 > number2)
End Sub

Private Sub RadioButton6_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RadioButton6.CheckedChanged
    updateUI(number1 >= number2)
End Sub
```

Comment: I want the entire form1 to change color, i appreciate the help

Comment: Updated, check it

Comment: Thank you very much Verdolino, im new to VB and was stuck with the code, very much appreciated <3

Comment: If his solution helped, upvote it and/or mark it as an answer...that is the preferred method of saying "thanks"